# Speed Up TextEditing on Long Text

Tags: text, swiftui

With the following code performance degrades drastically as the text gets longer due to the view getting redrawn for every character typed (due to textViewDidChange). There are also a number of nasty side effects as well, such as insertion of sentence breaks likely due to autocorrect or some other mechanism. If I comment out or eliminate the textViewDidChange function, performance is much better and the side effects disappear, but then I no longer can capture the text to save it or interrogate it on the fly.

Does anyone know of a way around this? I thought that if I could just not refresh the text variable until the focus was moved to a different view, then I could capture the text before it needs to be saved. If that might work, I can't determine how to trap the focus change. I have tried implementing textViewDidEndEditing but that only gets triggered when the parent view ends editing. I'm using a save button and want to capture the text then.

I realize that there is a TextEditor view available, but it is just as slow on large text so I assume it is doing the same thing.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var text: String
    @Binding var textStyle: UIFont.TextStyle
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let textView = UITextView()
        
        textView.delegate = context.coordinator
        textView.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: textStyle)
        textView.autocapitalizationType = .none
        textView.isSelectable = true
        textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        return textView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
        uiView.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: textStyle)
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator($text)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
        var text: Binding<String>

        init(_ text: Binding<String>) {
            self.text = text
        }
        
        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            self.text.wrappedValue = textView.text
        }
    }
}
```

Content View

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var message = ""
    @State private var textStyle = UIFont.TextStyle.body
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing) {
            TextView(text: $message, textStyle: $textStyle)
                .padding(.horizontal)
            
            Button(action: {
                self.textStyle = (self.textStyle == .body) ? .title1 : .body
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "textformat")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(Color.purple)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                
            }
            .padding()    
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Comment out the lines in the `update` function that is likely creating some weird loop. Only set the text there if it doesn't already match. Also pass the parent vs the Binding to the coordinator Binding does not work well in a class

Comment: I'm not experiencing any performance issues when using your code.